# Deno Fresh getting pathname

Tags: typescript, server-side-rendering, deno, freshjs

I'm quite new to deno and the Fresh framework (which is really hard to google for answers). I wanna make a nav link a different background color of it matches the pathname

this is what I tried:

```js
const NavLink = ({ href, children }: NavLinkProps) => {
  const isActive = location.pathname === href
  const bgClass = isActive ? tw`bg-gray-900` : tw`bg-transparent`

  return (
    <a
      href={href}
      className={tw`px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium text-white ${bgClass}`}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}
```

But `location` is undefined..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get current URL data from `PageProps.url` and pass it to your component.

From [the docs](https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/getting-started/dynamic-routes)

> The PageProps interface actually contains a bunch of useful properties
> that can be used to customize the rendered output. Next to the matched
> url pattern parameters, the raw url, and the route name can also be
> found in here.

```
const NavLink = ({ href, children, location }: NavLinkProps) => {
  const isActive = location.pathname === href
  const bgClass = isActive ? tw`bg-gray-900` : tw`bg-transparent`

  return (
    <a
      href={href}
      className={tw`px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium text-white ${bgClass}`}
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}

export default function Page(props: PageProps) {
  return (
    <div>You are on the page '{props.url.href}'.
      <NavLink href="/foo" children="Foo" location={props.url} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `data-[current]` option will be nicer. Also you don't need `tw` if you have version higher 1.1.

```
const NavLink = ({ href, children }: NavLinkProps) => {
  return (
    <a
      href={href}
      className="bg-transparent data-[current]:bg-gray-900 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium text-white"
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}
```

Comment: source - https://deno.com/blog/fresh-1.5#easier-active-link-styling